# Dismiss video when it is finished playing Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using the MPMoviePlayerController to play a video. I want to dismiss the video when it has finished playing. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class programViewController: UIViewController {

    var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        playVideo("video", type: "mov")
    }

    func playVideo(navn:String, type:String) {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(navn, ofType: type)
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFit
            player.shouldAutoplay = true
            player.fullscreen = false
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible just to delete the view from subviews, and because the last made subview is the movie player view you can delete it just by using this code:

```
self.view.subviews[self.view.subviews.count-1].removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add in playVideo function

```
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "movieFinishedCallback:", name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: player)
```

and in your classs:

```
    func movieFinishedCallback(notif:NSNotification) {
    // Obtain the reason why the movie playback finished
    var userInfo:Dictionary<String,Int!>  = notif.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,Int!>

    let finishReason : Int = userInfo[MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey]!

    // Dismiss the view controller ONLY when the reason is not "playback ended"
    if ( finishReason == MPMovieFinishReason.PlaybackEnded.rawValue)
    {
        let moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController = notif.object as! MPMoviePlayerController

        // Remove this class from the observers
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: self.moviePlayerController!.moviePlayer)

        // Dismiss the view controller
        moviePlayer.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! Good one.

Comment: Looks like you are only dismissing on PlaybackEnded

Answer (score 1):

updated version of @roman-barzyczak's answer:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(movieFinishedCallback(_:)), name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: moviePlayer)
```

then:

```
func movieFinishedCallback(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String : NSNumber] {
        let reason = userInfo[MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey]
        let finishReason = MPMovieFinishReason(rawValue: reason!.integerValue)

        if (finishReason != MPMovieFinishReason.PlaybackEnded),
            let moviePlayer = notification.object as? MPMoviePlayerController {

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: moviePlayer)
            moviePlayer.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to listen for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("playerPlaybackDidFinish"), name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)

// Present
self.presentViewController(moviePlayer, animated: ture, completion: nil)

// Dismiss
moviewPlayer.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What shall I write inside the "playerPlaybackDidFinish" func?

Comment: In my understanding you should present moviePlayer like this: self.presentViewController(mv, animated: ture, completion: nil)

Comment: And dismiss like this: moviePlayer.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Comment: Where should I set the self.presentViewController(moviePlayer, animated: ture, completion: nil)?

Comment: It is ok to write it in the viewDidLoad function.

Comment: How would you write the playVideo, and should I just dismiss it using the playerPlaybackDidFinish function and just the moviewPlayer.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)?